# Trigger back end processes through tableau and powerbi

Tags: powerbi, tableau-api

We need a build a front end for our python project that can trigger actions in python through an API. If we are using Django, we could link a button on the page to trigger an action on the backend.

But my organization uses tableau and powerbi and so far ,these tools as I understand can only work with ‘datasets’ as their source.
Can we make an API call to trigger a desired action on the backend through power bi or tableau? Like a ‘Run simulation’ or ‘Submit job’ type of button?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a [Power App](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/) to [call the API](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/calling-an-api-in-power-apps-portals-using-javascript/) and embed it in the Power BI report using [Power Apps visual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/powerapps-custom-visual).